# Получение скриншотов с RTSP потока

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, rtsp

Нужно брать скриншоты с RTSP потока, причём это не тривиальная задача по типу одного скриншота.

Мне надо создавать подключение к RTSP, а потом делать скриншот когда мне вздумается, по типу того как это сделано в VLC. Само собой, ffmpeg не подошёл, потому что он делает соединение, сразу делает скриншот и сбрасывает соединение. Таким образом для 10 скриншотов с камеры я получаю 10 подключений-отключений от RTSP потока, что вдобавок вызывает проблемы с задержкой скриншота.

Желательно, чтобы это была какая-либо утилита по типу ffmpeg, ActiveX или как .dll-библиотека, потому что все эти действия надо вызывать программно. Пробовал делать все это дело с помощью ActiveX компоненты от VLC, но там очень странно работает функция получения скриншота (она сохраняет это все в папку, не указанную в документации, а так же там нельзя указать путь к скриншоту и его тип).

Есть какие-либо ещё утилиты, которые могут мне помочь?

Comment: Можно над ffmpeg попробовать написать какую-нибудь python-обёртку, которая будет читать все кадры из ffmpeg и сохранять нужные скриншоты самостоятельно в любой момент времени (хотя звучит как-то костыльно)

Comment: @andreymal Тоже об этом думал, но тут реально костыль. Тем более я так и не смог разобраться как ffmpeg'у передавать команды во время его работы.

Comment: А передавать команды ему и не надо, достаточно из него кадры читать

Comment: @andreymal А останавливать его убивая процесс? Не будет ли RTSP поток дальше скитаться по сети, если ffmpeg не передал серверу что он отключается?

Comment: А, ну да, можно q в stdin подать, тоже не проблема)

Comment: А вообще по-хорошему нужно работать напрямую с ffmpeg-библиотеками (libavcodec/libavformat/libswscale), или можно попробовать взять какой-нибудь opencv, который уже слинкован с ffmpeg и умеет захватывать видео. Но я этим никогда не занимался и подробностей не знаю

Comment: питон прекрасно умеет кадры забирать из потока через OpenCV, в общем-то можно на чем угодно забирать через бинды к опенцв. хоть на питоне хоть на с++ хоть на c#. единственное чего там нет это возможность "промотать" н-кадров. т.е. читать придется постоянно весь поток. еще можно поискать сдк под вашу камеру и делать через сдк, но оно будет привязано к модели/вендору.

Comment: P.S. у некоторых камер, аля хик винжн / аксис, есть (S)API, которые дают возможность захватить одиночный кадр через HTTP-запрос. работает относительно быстро ~0.3-0.5 секунды и захватить можно откуда угодно, хоть из браузера на JS.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это можно посмотреть https://t-ev.ru/2016/12/jpeg-snapshot-rtsp/ У меня оно не поехало, но поток у меня с извращенной карты.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]